# Error: Const-method-handle are only supported starting with Android P (--min-api 28)

Tags: java, android-studio, jar

I try to package xx.jar into my apk. 
But when I compile my code , it will say

```
"Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing."

"Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete"

"Error: Const-method-handle are only supported starting with Android P (--min-api 28)".
```

I try search this problem with Google , but no result about this question.

How can I fix it?
Thx!

Comment: Set your project to source compatibility Java_1_8 https://forum.matomo.org/t/dexarchivebuilderexception-when-building-android-application-with-piwik-sdk/27518/2

Comment: yes! I work it out ! THX U VERY MUCH ! ! !
I find other answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49891730/invoke-customs-are-only-supported-starting-with-android-0-min-api-26