# Failed to process okhttp-3.14.0.jar

Tags: java, android, rest, okhttp

Trying to follow along a course on teamtreehouse on building an android weather app. The teacher is able get there app to run inside the emulator and crash, but mine won't even run in the emulator and just gives me a bunch of errors. The teacher has pointed out that there is intentional errors that will be fixed later on.

[image: Heres what some of the errors are.]

Comment: Have you tried the `gradle clean` action? Sometimes the gradle cache gets messed up and simply cleaning it fixes the problem.

Comment: How would i go about doing this? I am fairly new to android studio?

Comment: It should be available on the menu `Build > Clean project`. You can also open the terminal (on the bottom-left of AS) and run `./gradlew clean`.

Comment: That does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this to your `app/build.gradle` as noted [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50198499/3237900):

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```