# Invoke-customs Java error in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin

When I try to build the project I get the errors seen in the picture below. I updated the IDE and everything and even installed a new virtual phone but nothing changed. If I open the installed app it crashes instantly. I am new to Android Studio and programming in general and I have no clue what to do. I even tried to clean the project. It doesn't seam to have any errors in the part that I written. This occurred after I started adding Firebase. It might be a cache or version problem.
Thanks!

The full file with errors AbstractFuture.java was too long to be added so I only atached the part that has errors. Pretty much every "Safe", "compareAndSwapObject", "putObject" and "objectFieldOffset" is red.

```
private static final class UnsafeAtomicHelper extends AtomicHelper {
    static final sun.misc.Unsafe UNSAFE;
    static final long LISTENERS_OFFSET;
    static final long WAITERS_OFFSET;
    static final long VALUE_OFFSET;
    static final long WAITER_THREAD_OFFSET;
    static final long WAITER_NEXT_OFFSET;

    static {
      sun.misc.Unsafe unsafe = null;
      try {
        unsafe = sun.misc.Unsafe.getUnsafe();
      } catch (SecurityException tryReflectionInstead) {
        try {
          unsafe =
              AccessController.doPrivileged(
                  new PrivilegedExceptionAction<sun.misc.Unsafe>() {
                    @Override
                    public sun.misc.Unsafe run() throws Exception {
                      Class<sun.misc.Unsafe> k = sun.misc.Unsafe.class;
                      for (java.lang.reflect.Field f : k.getDeclaredFields()) {
                        f.setAccessible(true);
                        Object x = f.get(null);
                        if (k.isInstance(x)) {
                          return k.cast(x);
                        }
                      }
                      throw new NoSuchFieldError("the Unsafe");
                    }
                  });
        } catch (PrivilegedActionException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException("Could not initialize intrinsics", e.getCause());
        }
      }
      try {
        Class<?> abstractFuture = AbstractFuture.class;
        WAITERS_OFFSET = unsafe.objectFieldOffset(abstractFuture.getDeclaredField("waiters"));
        LISTENERS_OFFSET = unsafe.objectFieldOffset(abstractFuture.getDeclaredField("listeners"));
        VALUE_OFFSET = unsafe.objectFieldOffset(abstractFuture.getDeclaredField("value"));
        WAITER_THREAD_OFFSET = unsafe.objectFieldOffset(Waiter.class.getDeclaredField("thread"));
        WAITER_NEXT_OFFSET = unsafe.objectFieldOffset(Waiter.class.getDeclaredField("next"));
        UNSAFE = unsafe;
      } catch (Exception e) {
        throwIfUnchecked(e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }

    @Override
    void putThread(Waiter waiter, Thread newValue) {
      UNSAFE.putObject(waiter, WAITER_THREAD_OFFSET, newValue);
    }

    @Override
    void putNext(Waiter waiter, Waiter newValue) {
      UNSAFE.putObject(waiter, WAITER_NEXT_OFFSET, newValue);
    }

    /** Performs a CAS operation on the {@link #waiters} field. */
    @Override
    boolean casWaiters(AbstractFuture<?> future, Waiter expect, Waiter update) {
      return UNSAFE.compareAndSwapObject(future, WAITERS_OFFSET, expect, update);
    }

    /** Performs a CAS operation on the {@link #listeners} field. */
    @Override
    boolean casListeners(AbstractFuture<?> future, Listener expect, Listener update) {
      return UNSAFE.compareAndSwapObject(future, LISTENERS_OFFSET, expect, update);
    }

    /** Performs a CAS operation on the {@link #value} field. */
    @Override
    boolean casValue(AbstractFuture<?> future, Object expect, Object update) {
      return UNSAFE.compareAndSwapObject(future, VALUE_OFFSET, expect, update);
    }
  }
```

[image: build error picture]

**Error message:**

```
> Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project C:*****

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:processDebugManifest
C:***\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31:50 Warning:
    activity#com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FederatedSignInActivity@android:launchMode was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:24 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present

> Task :app:processDebugResources
> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
> Task :app:compileDebugSources
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dexBuilderDebug
> Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies
> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
WARNING: Compatible side by side NDK version was not found. Default is 21.0.6113669.
Compatible side by side NDK version was not found. Default is 21.0.6113669.

> Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug

> Task :app:mergeDexDebug
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 185800 > 65536 ; # fields: 100419 > 65536)","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:132)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:119)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskRunnable.run(DexMergingTask.kt:441)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade.run(Workers.kt:242)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AdapterWorkAction.execute(AdapterWorkAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:50)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:63)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:98)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:53)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$2(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:200)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:215)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.W.a(:87)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(:11)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:117)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.b: Error: null, Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 185800 > 65536 ; # fields: 100419 > 65536)
    at Version.fakeStackEntry(Version_2.0.74.java:0)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.M0.a(:21)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.P.a(:56)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.P$h.a(:7)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.b.a(:15)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.b.b(:24)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(:87)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(:1)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.W.a(:30)
    ... 35 more


> Task :app:mergeDexDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
     The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
     Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 38s
23 actionable tasks: 8 executed, 15 up-to-date
```

**This is from where I took the Circle Image View**

[link for circle image view GitHub](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView)

[Building app error photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HGtl.png)

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49891730/invoke-customs-are-only-supported-starting-with-android-0-min-api-26

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but I only got more errors

Comment: Could you post the errors?  It sounds like there might be other errors that this error was hiding, and that actually is the solution to _this_ problem.

Comment: Thank you @RyanM . Here is the link for the completed question with the errors shown but I'll try to add it here too  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62244705/appmergedexdebug-build-error-android-studio-abstractfuture-java-problem)

Comment: Yeah, it looks like that solved this problem and now you're having another problem.  Thanks for the question link, I've added a suggestion over there.