# Trying to use a JAR created with Clojure in Android

Tags: java, android, gradle, clojure

I want to use Clojure to create a library that I'll use in an Android project.

Experimenting with this, I've made an Uberjar from a test library in Leiningen.

Then I import it into my Android project.

But I'm getting this error :

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"MethodHandle.invoke and MethodHandle.invokeExact are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform file 'mylib.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=23, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime-jars}
      > Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: /media/phil/54AE4F563BCE86E8/DATA/new_dev_tree/small_experiments/clj-jar-for-android/TestAJar/app/libs/mylib.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
   > Failed to transform file 'mylib.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=23, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime-jars}
      > Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: /media/phil/54AE4F563BCE86E8/DATA/new_dev_tree/small_experiments/clj-jar-for-android/TestAJar/app/libs/mylib.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
```

What exactly is going wrong here? Is it about the Android version? Or the file path? Or something completely different?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49891730/invoke-customs-are-only-supported-starting-with-android-0-min-api-26

Comment: Thanks ... .I tried that. Still getting an error, but it's changed slightly.